# How to install monodevelop 5 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, monodevelop

I want to install monodevelop 5 on ubuntu 14.04 64bit PC, I have followed this [how to install monodevelop 5.1 on ubuntu](https://anangbakti.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/install-monodevelop-5-1-on-fresh-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64bit/)  way but it gives me some error at the step 4 and 5.

after this command **./configure –profile=stable** it gives the following error 
[image: monoerror]

Comment: And what are "some errors"?

Comment: its like configure error and directory not found error

Comment: Compiling MonoDevelop from source, especially from Git, is a very bad idea. That how-to is very bad. If you check the official MonoDevelop website (which you should always do before reading a how-to), it has official, better directions on how to install MonoDevelop, and it allows you to install it with Ubuntu's package manager, APT. Read here (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives). Make sure you remove all of the packages that the how-to you read told you to install.

Comment: question edited.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste : I have read the official tut but cannot understand properly.

Comment: Okay. I'll write an answer for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than building MonoDevelop from source, it is much better to follow the directions on [the MonoDevelop website](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives).

**This guide should only be followed if you are both running Ubuntu 14.04 and you need MonoDevelop version 5.**

If you're on Ubuntu 14.04 and you only need MonoDevelop 4, you can run `sudo apt-get install monodevelop`.

If you're on a version of Ubuntu newer than 14.04, you can install MonoDevelop 5 just by running `sudo apt-get install monodevelop`.

If you're on Ubuntu 14.04 and need version 5, run the following commands, one after the other.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` isn't really needed...

Comment: @wb9688 I really don't think it is either, so I'm removing it. I just put it there because the MonoDevelop people had it.